# ArcPy Export to PDF not working

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pdf

I have ArcMap 10.5 installed in my PC and I'm using ArcPy to updated different MXDs and then export PDF.

This one is a very simple and plain script, but I can't figure out why it's not exporting the PDF.

It returns the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/automatelayouts.py", line 71, in <module>
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd_copy_path_obj, pdf_out_path,resolution=150)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1156, in ExportToPDF
    layout.exportToPDF(*args)
AttributeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToPDF
```

Here is my script:

### Script:

```
import arcpy
import os

area_path=os.environ['USERPROFILE']

run_number = "1"
parameter_folder=os.path.join(area_path,r"Desktop\test\input\parameters")
input_mxd_folder=os.path.join(area_path,r"Desktop\test\input\mxd")
lyrfolder=os.path.join(area_path,r"Desktop\test\input\lyr")
output_mxd_folder= os.path.join(area_path,r"Desktop\test\output\mxd\run"+run_number)
if not os.path.isdir(output_mxd_folder): os.makedirs(output_mxd_folder)
output_pdf_folder= os.path.join(area_path,r"Desktop\test\output\pdf\run"+run_number)
if not os.path.isdir(output_pdf_folder): os.makedirs(output_pdf_folder)

title="Krigging Map  -  Aluminum"
metal="Aluminum"

input_parameter_shp=os.path.join(parameter_folder,"Aluminium_area.shp")
mxd_template_list=["report1.mxd","report2.mxd","report3.mxd"]
fig=0
for mxd_template_name in mxd_template_list:
    fig+=1
    print("creating figure_"+str(fig))
    pdf_name=mxd_template_name.replace(".mxd","_"+metal+".pdf")
    pdf_out_path = os.path.join(output_pdf_folder,pdf_name)
    if not os.path.isfile( pdf_out_path ):
        mxd_template_path=os.path.join(input_mxd_folder,(mxd_template_name))
        mxd_copy_name=mxd_template_name.replace(".mxd","_"+metal+".mxd")
        print("--mxd_copy_name: "+mxd_copy_name)
        mxd_copy_path=os.path.join(output_mxd_folder,mxd_copy_name)

        print("creating the map document for the template mxd...")
        mxd_template_path_obj = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_template_path)
        print("making a copy from template mxd...")
        mxd_template_path_obj.saveACopy(mxd_copy_path)
        print("Deleting template MXD to free up memory...")
        del mxd_template_path_obj

        mxd_copy_path = os.path.join(output_mxd_folder,mxd_copy_name)

        print("creating a new map document for the copied mxd...")
        mxd_copy_path_obj = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_copy_path)
        
        print("finding the metal layer...")
        lyr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd_copy_path_obj,"metal")[0] 

        print("executing arcpy.Describe...")
        desc=arcpy.Describe(input_parameter_shp)
        print("replacing the lyr datasource...")
        lyr.replaceDataSource(desc.path,"SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE",desc.basename)
        print("updating table of contents...")
        arcpy.RefreshTOC() 

        style_lyr= os.path.join(lyrfolder,"aluminium.lyr")
        print("updating symbology...")
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, style_lyr)
        
        print("updating element name texts...")
        title_text=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd_copy_path_obj,"TEXT_ELEMENT","titulo")[0]
        title_text.text=title
        figure_number_text=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd_copy_path_obj,"TEXT_ELEMENT","figura")[0]
        figure_number_text.text="Figura "+str(fig)

        print("saving the copied mxd...")
        mxd_copy_path_obj.save()

        print("exporting PDF...")
        
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd_copy_path_obj, pdf_out_path,resolution=150)
        print("PDF saved successfully...")
        
        print("Deleting MXD to free up memory...")
        del mxd_copy_path_obj
        
        print("finishing iteration {}...\n\n".format(fig))

print("SCRIPT FINISHED...")
```

Comment: Your script worked for me...Except I commented out lines 44-62. If the PDF file already exists, is there a lock on it? An easy way to check for a lock on the file is to try and rename it in Windows-Explorer. Sometimes ArcMap holds locks on PDFs. Also, do you have write-access to the output folder location (seems unlikely you would not have access, but worth a shot)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where the script or updatemap class exports to PDF ([arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm)). Adding an "exportPDF" method to your class, then calling it in the script worked for me.

```
    def exportPDF(self, pdfPath):
        """doc string"""
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(self.mxd, pdfPath)
```

Unrelatedly, I suggest using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build your paths.

For example:

```
savemxdfolder = os.path.join(workspace, "outmxd") # <-- This
savemxdfolder = workspace+"\outmxd" #<--- Instead of this
```

Comment: The ExportToPDF function is near the bottom of the script nested into the for/if not section.  It is above the 4th from last print statement.

Comment: It appears to have been added in an edit, in addition to a lot of other script, and the "updatemap" class has been removed.